# Backbone routing and view relations

Tags: view, routes

I'm preparing to build a medium sized website with Backbone for the first time. There are 7 menu items, and I cant figure out whats the best routing/view relationship when it comes to performance. When a route is triggered, do I create a new instance of the "active" view every time it's triggered or do I only create one view instance for each view, when the user loads the page?

... And whats the best way to handle views – adding and removing dom elements and events, without having trouble with performance. e.g.

```
$('selector').html(my-new-view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your menu only once, if it doesnt change. You can create some html template like this.

```
<div>
    <nav>render-here-only-one</nav>
    <section>render-here-when-page-changes/loads</section>
</div>
```

I prefer backbone's render method initialize and append itself.

```
var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#section"),
    template:_.template("<strong>hello.</strong>")
    initialize: function () { 
        // any change on view will trigger render
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },
    render: function (item) { 
        this.el.html(this.template());
    }
});

var myView = new testView();
    myView.render();
```